Can I sue Walmart for trespassing me based on a false accusation?
About a week ago I was shopping at a Walmart superstore and was enjoying lemonade in a dining area of the store when six police officers walked in, one with a shotgun, had me stand up, put me in handcuffs took me outside the store and questioned me.
Apparently an employee of Walmart had told Walmart security that I had said to them that I wanted to bomb the store. I've never said such a thing to anyone in my life nor did I say anything like that to any employee in the store while shopping.
After questioning me the police let me go and then were present when a Walmart security person came out and told me that I was trespassed from the store for a year.
I am completely 100% innocent and I'm wondering if I can sue them for defamation and civil liability and potentially sue them under other areas of law.
Walmart should not be allowed to do this to anyone they wish for no reason at all.

Well I don't know if they are happy about it but in the presence of the police they couldn't apparently trespass me for longer.

My wife got trespassed from Target for no reason at all.  They wouldn't tell us anything about why they trespassed her.

Just FYI, I'm not an expert on the use of the word "trespassed", but as far as I know, someone is considered to be "trespassing" when they are on a property illegally, but when a party is prohibited from being on a property it's not called "trespassed".  There could be a slight language translation issue here, so I thought I would mention it to help you out.  I think the word you want to use is perhaps "prohibited".

@EndAntisemiticHate "Trespassed" is a relatively recent slang term that means you are banned from the property in the U.S. that is slowly becoming an accepted usage a bit like the trend towards using the word "gifted' when you mean "gave", and similar to the trend towards saying that someone was "garnisheed" instead of "garnished." The term "trespassed" in this sense is often used by retail stores and their security teams and managers.

Presumably it derives from the fact that you're considered to be trespassing if you enter a place where you're banned.

Until you posted this question, no one knew about the accusation against you. You're the one who made it public (assuming people can trace it back to you), it wasn't defamation before.

@ohwilleke Thank you for providing the new definition of "trespassed" in colloquial American English. (The snarky part of me wants to put English in quotes there, but I'll resist!)   I had no idea.  Now I do!

Walmart is allowed to do this to anyone they wish for no reason at all, other than a specifically prohibited reason (e.g. race, disability, religion). They have an essentially absolute say over who they will do business with or allow onto their property.

can sue them for defamation and civil liability and potentially sue
them under other areas of law.

Walmart didn't go and tell people other than Walmart and the police (whom they have a legally protected right to express their concerns to without liability) that you said you are going to bomb the store. They simply made an internal decision. This isn't defamation.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Falsely calling the police for someone is probably criminal offense. "Misleading authority" and "false witness" and "threating with public danger" are terminologies coming into my mind. Neither of them are things what a sane guy would risk, even if he has a bad day..

@GraySheep The discussion in the chat addresses some of these issues. It isn't clear that the police were "falsely called" as opposed to mistakenly classed.
